# qterminal -e option - adding more arguments

Tags: qt

I am successfully using QT `qterminal`, however, the `-e` option will work only with single argument.

What I need in pseudo code is
`qterminal -e bluetoothctl help`

what is working is

`qterminal -e bluetoothctl`

My next step is to analyze the actual qterminal source code to see how to accomplish the task at hand .

I am posting this here **in case somebody already knows** how to pass optional arguments to the qterminal. The manual does not elaborate on how to do that.

If you have no knowledge about qterminal, keep it to yourself, no need to advertise that here. I am asking for a solution , not social discussion.

I will greatly appreciate such solution.

Comment: `qterminal -e 'bluetoothctl help'`?  Just a guess.

Comment: Another guess `qterminal -e bluetoothctl -e help`?

Comment: Appreciate the replyies - the argimnets are passed to the QProcess as QStringList.

Comment: Here are the latest tests results 
using gnome-terminal and “--”<<”bluetothcth” <<”--”<<”help” starts and show the terminal with an error “cannot find child file  “help”
using qterminal  and “-e”<<”bluetothcth” <<”-e”<<”help” does not even start the QProcess  and QT gives no error

Answer (score 1):

The only "terminal" application which actually spells  out executable options - in plural - is "xterm" . And it actually DOES work as advertised.  The moral of the story - RTFM is no good if it does not tell the real story.